# Time series forecasting $y_t$ with other features $X_t$ and all past information

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I meet a time series problem.

For machine learning problem, with data set $\{(X_i, y_i) | i = 1, \cdots, n\}$, we want to predict y given some X. There are many ML model to do such kind fitting, e.g. linear regression, CNN, etc.

For time series problem, with $\{Y_t | t = 1, \cdots, k\}$, we want to predict $Y_n$ for $n > k$. There are also lots of time series model, e.g. ARIMA, etc.

Right now, I meet a problem, with time series dataset $\{(X^1_t, X^2_t, \cdots, X^m_t, y_t) | t = 1, \cdots ,k\}$ where $X^k_t$ is feature $X^k$ at time t. We want to predict $y_n (n > t)$ given previous dataset and $\{X^1_n, \cdots, X^m_n\}$.

My questions:

1. What's terminology for this kind of problem?
2. Has this problem been systematically studied? Could you give some reference or literature?
3. What are the famous models for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $Y$ is a continuous variable, the main difference in a general regression problem (what you called 'machine learning') and time series analysis is that the latter contains observations indexed in time order.

1. This is both multivariate regression problem, since there are multiple independent variables, and a time series problem. I believe the term [Dynamic Regression](https://otexts.com/fpp2/dynamic.html) is also used.
2. Usually you create a regression problem where the dependent variables include exogenous regressors $X$ and past observations of the target variable $Y$.
3. Classical time series models can be extended to include exogenous regressors (for example [ARIMAX](https://otexts.com/fpp2/regarima.html)). Moreover, you can include past observations of $Y$ in the dependent variables and apply *any* regression algorithm from the machine learning literature.

There are also hybrid approaches. [Here](http://henrikmadsen.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Journal_article_-_2013_-_Forecasting_Electricity_Spot_Prices_Accounting_for_Wind_Power_Predictions.pdf) is an example where a multivariate regression is first applied (only exogenous variables) and then ARIMA is used to model the residuals.